# Is it allowed to use member variable of passing argument class object in defining class member function?

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm using Xcode to compile the code. I think there should be a logical error but compiler doesn't raise any error.

Is it allowed to use member variable of passing argument class instance in defining class member function?

```
bool Foo::operator <(const Foo& f){
    if(dist < f.dist){
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

dist is a member variable and I don't really get why compiler allowed the function to use member variable of " f " instacne in defining member function of Class Foo.

Comment: Unrelated comment: Just `return dist < f.dist;`. There's no need to use an `if` statement to return a Boolean result from a Boolean expression.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Helped a lot!